# query plan shows key lookup with 99% when search condition value is null

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2014, sql-execution-plan

I have a SP the sp execute on a table with an index in three columns col_1,col_2,col_3,col_4,col_n. Col 1 is an identity. there is an index on col_2,col_3,col_4 in that order.

When I query something like

```
@parameter=1

SELECT col_2,col_3,col_4
WHERE col_2=@parameter
AND col_3='2'
AND col_4=10.00
```

It uses the index I mention before but if I query something like

```
@paramete =null; -- the parameter is null in this case when parameter
has value it uses the index

SELECT col_2,col_3,col_4
WHERE (@parameter is null OR col_2 = @parameter)
AND col_3='2'
AND col_4=10.00
```

It shows a query plan with a key look up on col_1 with a 99% cost.

Sometimes the value is null and I must remain like that.

Can someone explain this? can it be fixed?

Thanks.

Comment: This exactly how this type of query will always work. It is commonly known as a "catch all" query. Here is an excellent article discussing this type of query and how you can fix it. https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/how-to-confuse-the-sql-server-query-optimizer/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, add `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` to the query:

```
SELECT col_2,col_3,col_4
WHERE 
    (@parameter is null OR col_2 = @parameter)
    AND col_3='2'
    AND col_4=10.00
OPTION(RECOMPILE);
```

See excellent article [Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) by Erland Sommarskog for details.

---

If `@parameter` is not NULL, with `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` the query effectively becomes this:

```
SELECT col_2,col_3,col_4
WHERE 
    col_2 = <actual_parameter_value>
    AND col_3='2'
    AND col_4=10.00
```

An index on `col_2,col_3,col_4` can be used to quickly find necessary rows in this query.

---

If `@parameter` is NULL, with `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` the query effectively becomes this:

```
SELECT col_2,col_3,col_4
WHERE 
    col_3='2'
    AND col_4=10.00
```

Now it is obvious that index on `col_2,col_3,col_4` is of no help here. You need a second index on `col_3,col_4 include (col_2)` to make it efficient.

---

On the other hand, a single index with different order of columns would help in both cases. So, instead of index on `col_2,col_3,col_4` create and index on `col_4,col_3,col_2` or `col_3,col_4,col_2`. Put `col_2` last in the index definition. It will be used efficiently in both cases (with `OPTION(RECOMPILE)`).